# Cannot get ID of DIV created with PHP

Tags: php, post, dom, dynamic

I have a user dashboard page where every time they visit it, it pulls all of their personal times in a database based on the session email. It builds a list of all their items for them to view. I want them to be able to click on one of the items and then it directs to a search page using the div id or value as the MySQL search parameter. The problem is that I cannot get the div id.. or value... or class. It comes up as blank when I try to alert(this.id).. or undefined if I alert(this.className).

Here is my code:

```
function getAllMyItems_itemsTable2(string $email){
    include 'config.php';
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM itemsTable WHERE email= :email';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);       
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $getResults = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo '<div class="w3-card w3-white" style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px;">';
    echo '<div class="row" style="text-align: left;">';
    echo '<div class="col-md-3" style="border-bottom: solid 1px gray;">Item Name</div><hr>';
    echo '<div class="col-md-3" style="border-bottom: solid 1px gray;">Added Time</div><hr>';
    echo '<div class="col-md-3" style="border-bottom: solid 1px gray;">Pieces</div><hr>';
    echo '<div class="col-md-3" style="border-bottom: solid 1px gray;">Description</div><hr>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="row" style="text-align: left;">';
    foreach( $getResults as $row) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-3" id="'.$row['itemName'].'" value="'.$row['itemName'].'"><a href="#">'.$row['itemName'].'</a></div>';
        echo '<div class="col-md-3">'.$row['addedTime'].'</div>';
        echo '<div class="col-md-3">'.$row['pieces'].'</div>';
        echo '<div class="col-md-3">'.$row['description'].'</div>';
    }
    echo "</div>";     
}
```

I want to be able to click on the div id = $row['itemName'] and it grab that name and pass it to the next page to perform a search. Is there a better way to go about this?

HTML Part:

```
<div class="resultsContainer" style="text-align: center;">
    <?php
 if(!getNumberOfItems_itemsTable($email) == 0){
        echo getAllMyItems_itemsTable2($email);
        }
        ?>
    </div>


<script>

  $('.resultsContainer').click(function(){
  alert(this.id);
  });

    </script>
```

Comment: Please show us your javascript where the event handlers are setup.

Comment: edited - I was hoping that clicking on each div within the resultsContainer would show that specific id. But this just returns an empty alert box.

Comment: Right, you are only putting a click event on the whole container. Not what you actually clicked on. So `this` only refers to the container.

Comment: You do know that you don't have to echo every line like that, don't you? You can close your php tag and use plain html, then whenever you want to use a variable, just open the tag and echo it, then close the tag again. Echoing every line is a headache, escaping characters, quotes, etc... and it is more prone to silly errors.

Comment: I see. So I would need to specify the child elements somehow even though they are dynamically generated and their id's will not be known?

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind, is you might want to add a letter to the beginning of your ID's, because numbers are not allowed as the first character in a ID field in html. If dynamically created, it is the surest way to ensure a valid character starts the ID name.

Comment: That is a very good suggestion. These are little things that I'm not aware of at my current level if experience that i'm sure would cause me MUCH grief later on. Thank you, Gary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are only putting a click event on the whole container. Not what you actually clicked on. So that only refers to the container...

Since you dont have a different class on the div with the unique ids, it is hard to set a click event for just those divs. You may want to add a class on the div with the id. Then you can change your event handler to respond to those specifically.

An example:

```
echo '<div class="col-md-3 actionable" id="'.$row['itemName'].'" value=.....';
                         //^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then:

```
$('div.actionable').on('click',function(){
 //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    alert( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

Note I changed the reference for the id, to be more jquery-like since you are within jquery. Might as well stay consistent ;)

Comment: Yessssss! That got it. I really appreciate it, IncredibleHat.

Comment: Opens the mind a bit, the power of class vs id event handler tagging :)